# Issue in retrieving a property mapped with a BigInteger in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

I encountered an issue regarding retrieval of 10^18 digit number using Hibernate. Although I am not entirely sure if it's an Oracle Database, Grails, Hibernate, or Java issue entirely. Considering this Grails domain class:

```
class Payment {
    BigInteger id
    BigDecimal amount

    static mapping = {        
        id generator: "assigned"
        version false
    }
}
```

I encounter the issue through the retrieval:

```
Payment savePayment() {
    BigInteger id = 201910151421550246D
    BigDecimal amount = 100.00G

    Payment payment = new Payment()

    payment.id = id
    payment.amount amount

    payment.save(flush: true)

    Payment retrievedPayment = Payment.findById(id)

    println "payment.id: " + payment.id
    println "payment.amount: " + payment.amount
    println "retrievedPayment.id: " + retrievedPayment.id
    println "retrievedPayment.amount: " + retrievedPayment.amount

    // payment.id: 201910151421550246
    // payment.amount: 100.00
    // retrievedPayment.id: 201910151421550240
    // retrievedPayment.amount: 100.00

    return retrievedPayment
}
```

I assigned `201910151421550246` as id before saving and also confirmed it's value if its the same on the database. And it is. Also when I tried to retrieve the said record using that `id`, I can still retrieve the same `Payment` record. The problem is why the value is off by six points? I'm currently mapping it to `String` data type and convert it to BigInteger when I need to perform numeric operations as a temporary solution.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/7132bb2f799b937c25e7626ff7dd9fee

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem of Oracle database or Java BigInteger or hibernate  as they supports more than 201910151421550246 number.

In context of web application, value greater than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER is not considered reliable for browser.

Like when we print console.log(201910151421550246); in javascript, we get 201910151421550240 as output.

So, if you want to use number greater than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER on, then convert it to String and then use it.

Comment: "In context of web application, value greater than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER is not considered reliable for browser." - This does not make sense to me as a response the question asked.  You would see the exact same behavior even if this weren't a web app.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown  I have no knowledge about Grails but I can tell you that the asked question will not produce any issue when you will run on Java Web server or if you run as java Stand alone application. But when you will print the number greater than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER on browser, It may change.

Comment: "I have no knowledge about Grails but I can tell you that the asked question will not produce any issue when you will run on Java Web server or if you run as java Stand alone application." - I believe that is incorrect.  Our GORM implementation and Hibernate treat this exactly the same with respect to this outside of a web app.

Answer (score 0):

The first lines of the gist are the clue. You are defining a Double with the literal "D" suffix, and Double cannot exactly represent the integer you desire. See "[Floating-Point Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)". When cast to BigInteger there is a rounding error. Use a String to create the BigInteger, or for literals the dual-duty [G suffix](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-256) which works for both BigInteger and BigDecimal.

```
groovy:000> i=201910151421550246D
===> 2.0191015142155024E17
groovy:000> i.class
===> class java.lang.Double
groovy:000> j=(BigInteger)i
===> 201910151421550240
groovy:000> j.class
===> class java.math.BigInteger
groovy:000> id = new BigInteger("201910151421550246")
===> 201910151421550246
groovy:000> id.class
===> class java.math.BigInteger
groovy:000> b=201910151421550246G
===> 201910151421550246
groovy:000> b.class
===> class java.math.BigInteger
groovy:000> id==b
===> true
groovy:000> d=100.0G
===> 100.0
groovy:000> d.class
===> class java.math.BigDecimal
```